# Overgrive 3.3.10 install error on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation

I just installed Overgrive 3.3.10 and got the following error message when launching it:
python /opt/thefanclub/overgrive/overgrive
File "/opt/thefanclub/overgrive/overgrive", line 5
m
Z
m
Z
m
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Any idea to help ?
Thanks
Pascal

Comment: Please add `head -n5 /opt/thefanclub/overgrive/overgrive` to the question by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install all upgrades to the current system first by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and be sure that you are running completely updated Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Then retry OverGrive reinstallation by

```
cd /tmp
wget -c https://www.thefanclub.co.za/sites/default/files/public/overgrive/overgrive_3.3.10_all.deb
sudo apt-get purge --autoremove overgrive
sudo apt-get install ./overgrive_3.3.10_all.deb
```

and launch it again.

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion. 
In the meantime i upgraded to Ubuntu 21.04. Receiving your suggestion, i applied your action plan but I have now the following error:
python /opt/thefanclub/overgrive 
usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in '/opt/thefanclub/overgrive'
More idea to help ?

Comment: What is the output of `python3 /opt/thefanclub/overgrive/overgrive`?

Comment: [INFO] Linux-5.11.0-38-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.33
[INFO] Python 3.9.5
[INFO] Desktop : ubuntu
[CONFIG] Loading User Settings GUI mode
[CONFIG] Auto Sync : True
[CONFIG] Convert Google Docs : False
[CONFIG] Remove Items : True
[CONFIG] Backup Only : False

Then I have a panel with following info:
 Cannot load Google App Data
This error prevent overGrive to start
Try to start the app in a moment

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kt5mbhzb3rk3oti/OverGrive%20error_%202021-11-08%2013-16-03.png?dl=0
Above a screenshot of the error.
Thx for your help
Pascal